# Use a light font weight with Sifr

Tags: flash, text, sifr, sifr3, embedded-fonts

With sifr, how do I make a font use the light weight version. I have...

```
var gillsans = { src: '/resources/swf/gillsans.swf' };

sIFR.activate(gillsans);

sIFR.replace(gillsans, {
 selector: 'h1',
 css: '.sIFR-root { background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #000000; text-transform:uppercase; }'
});
```

which is displaying regular Gill Sans, the light version has been exported with the swf (said so in the export report), but how do I get it to display in sifr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify it in the sifr config, you have to use the 'Thin' version of the font when you export it from flash.

Answer (score 0):

If you've only exported the Light version, it should be selected automatically. Otherwise try specifying `font-family` for `.sIFR-root`.